# Suppress warning import of legacy library into null safe

Tags: flutter

How can I suppress this warning? I tried putting `import_of_legacy_library_into_null_safe: false` in rules in the analisys file but it doesn't work.

Comment: The warning is there as a warning.  It's not stopping you from building, but you really really ought to update or replace your legacy libraries by now.

Comment: I know, this is what I am trying to do but it will take me a long time because there are  hundreds of files and the priority is not migrating to null safety but implementing new features. I have so many warnings of this type that i have difficulty in seeing other errors, this is why i need to temporary disable this rule.